# Кастомный гео-объект и RemoteObjectManager

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть задача - нарисовать на карте нестандартный объект - этакий контур сосиски, которая начинается с одной точке, кончается в другой, имеет bubble и ведёт себя как placemark (drag не требуется). Толщина "сосиски" задаётся в пикселах и не зависит от масштаба.

В тестовых целях я взял пример со стрелочкой https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/arrow и переделал отрисовку. Получилось то, что нужно.

Но задача сложнее: то же самое надо провернуть с RemoteObjectManager. Вот тут https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/remote-object-manager/backend-docpage/ написано, что через json можно отрисовывать только метку, линию, круг или многоугольник.

Я попробовал рисовать линию, задав для неё lineStringOverlay, но меня это не спасло. Отрисовался отрезок.

Конечно, я могу сформировать на стороне сервера соответствующий полигон, причём придётся пересчитывать его размеры в гео-координаты самостоятельно, но подобное решение выглядит криво. Нельзя ли всё таки как-то задать собственный оверлей для линии?

У кого есть идеи, как такое сделать?

Если сформулировать кодом, то вот так не работает (рисуется прямая)

```
ymaps.modules.require(['overlay.BiPlacemark'], function (BiPlacemarkOverlay) {
        ymaps.overlay.storage.add("BiPlacemarkOverlay", BiPlacemarkOverlay);

    var objectManager = new ymaps.RemoteObjectManager(apiBase + '/ymaps-tile-ww?bbox=%b&zoom=%z&link_type=' + t.catalogLinkType, {
.....
        });

        myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
});
```

А в geoJson

```
{
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 61955,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          ..........
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        ........
      },
      "options": {
        .....
        "lineStringOverlay": "BiPlacemarkOverlay",
      }
    }
  ],
  "type": "FeatureCollection"
}
```

При этом вот такая конструкция вполне работает (рисуется то, что задумано):

```
                        ymaps.modules.require(['overlay.BiPlacemark'], function (BiPlacemarkOverlay) {
        ymaps.overlay.storage.add("BiPlacemarkOverlay", BiPlacemarkOverlay);
                            var biPlacemark = new ymaps.GeoObject({
                                geometry: {
                                    type: "LineString",
                                    coordinates: [p1,p2],
                                },
                                properties: {}
                            }, {
                                lineStringOverlay: "BiPlacemarkOverlay",
                            });
                            map.geoObjects.add(biPlacemark);
                        });
```

Comment: Пробовали задавать опцию "overlay": "BiPlacemarkOverlay" ? https://jsfiddle.net/eb9om7ha/1/

Comment: Спасибо! Да, работает!

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround**
Поскольку в моём варианте надо поменять отрисовку всех lineString на карте, пришлось подменить в хранилище дефолтный оверлей.

```
 ymaps.overlay.storage.add("default#polyline", BiPlacemarkOverlay);
```

Поле lineStringOverlay в options для geoJson, увы, заставть работать не получилось